# Creating a new remote repository on GitHub using git remote add origin

Tags: git, github

I following a Git tutorial and I've got stuck on the creation of a new remote repository.

I've understood that the command **git remote add origin**  would create a new repo named testingGit on https://github.com/natalisilverio/ but visiting the list of my repositories I can see that it was not created.

My intention is to learn how to create a remote repository using **terminal** and not in github.com. Is that possible? If if yes, what I am doing wrong?

Here follows the entire code I typed in terminal:

```
git init

git remote add origin https://github.com/natalisilverio/testingGit.git

git add test.rtf

git commit -m "adding test.rtf”

git remote add origin https://github.com/natalisilverio/testingGit.git 

git push -u origin master (and then I provide my user and password)

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/natalisilverio/testingGit.git/' not found
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `git remote add origin` will not create a new repository on github.

Adding a *remote* is simply saying "here is a URL to another copy of this repository". In order to satisfy this you would still need to have created the repository on github first.

Creating a repository on github in this way is not a common usage, but it is possible via the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create).

More likely, you will want to create your repository first on github and then clone it locally. Or if you already have a local project, you can create a new repository on Github (via the web interface) and add your project to it. See [Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's not possible using plain Git commands. Though in case of Github you can use Github API to do so.

This should create a new remote repository

```
curl -u "natalisilverio" -d "{\"name\":\"testingGit\"}" https://api.github.com/user/repos

or 

curl -u "natalisilverio" -d '{"name":"testingGit"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

*Edits

Entering this command should directly ask for the user's password. If you want to pass the password in the first command directly it can be done as below

```
curl -u "username:password" -d '{"name":"new-repo-name"}'
```

However this may leave your password in the command line history (for example in .bashhistory) so be careful.

Git command **git remote add** just keeps track of existing remote repositories. I does a little more than to define a variable to hold remote repository link for current local repository.

Comment: When we enter the command directly to command line, it will ask for the password itself. Just tested it. I'll try to leave the authentication parts if someone wants to use it inside an automated script.